# Unable to click element by id , python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I am trying to find and click the element but it's not working . The HTML code is following

`<a href="#" class="button blue block" id="tollstation">Toll Plaza(s) Between Two Stations </a>`

I am trying as follow

`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'tollstation')))`

and other one

`element = driver.find_element_by_id('tollstation')
element.click()`

but it's not working .  plz help..

Comment: is tollstation id is unique? .. there is any frame present on DOM

Comment: are you sure that the page is being loaded?

Comment: Yes The page is being loaded,
here is my code

`path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Users/prash/Desktop/WebScrap/selenium/chromedriver' 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
url = 'http://tis.nhai.gov.in/tollplazasonmap?language=en'
browser.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_id('tollstation')
element.click()
element2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button green')
driver.find_element_by_id('txtfrom').send_keys("Delhi")
driver.find_element_by_id('txtto').send_keys("Bangalore")
element2.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have no knowledge of python so i make code in java, please convert it to python

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\software and tools\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://tis.nhai.gov.in/tollplazasonmap?language=en");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement frame1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//embed[@src='map1.htm']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame1);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement tollstation= driver.findElement(By.id("tollstation"));
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",tollstation);
```

Comment: Please keep the question on topic - the OP specifically asked for a solution using Python

Comment: Please keep the question on topic - the OP specifically asked for a solution using Python

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code and lets see if it works-

```
driver.get(url) 
embed = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('embed') 
driver.switch_to.frame(embed) 
element = driver.find_element_by_id('tollstation') 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

ANSWER FOR THE QUESTION IN COMMENTS-

Instead of -

```
element2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button green')
```

Use below code-

```
element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='showstation']/p[7]/a")
```

Comment: but after this when I am filling the data 

`element2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button green')
driver.find_element_by_id('txtfrom').send_keys("Delhi")
driver.find_element_by_id('txtto').send_keys("Bangalore")
element2.click()`
again its not happening....

Comment: Dude, the words like 'Not Happening'/ 'Not working' won't help you out. You need to tell us the DOM and the error you are getting.

Comment: When I tried like 
`driver.find_element_by_id('txtfrom').send_keys("Delhi")
#driver.find_element_by_id('txtto').send_keys("Bangalore")`

the error is coming
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"txtfrom"}`

Comment: and when I tried by 
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('txtfrom').send_keys("Delhi")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('txtto').send_keys("Bangalore")`
The error is 
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"txtfrom"}`

Comment: Put some wait between click and  'txtfrom' send_keys("Delhi") line of code.

Comment: when I am filling the txtfrom (1st textbox) as delhi , then 4 option are displaying for select one. is there any way to select 1st option and move to 2nd text box?

Comment: Just click anywhere on the page after entering Delhi and same for Bangalore. Something like driver.find_element_by_id('showstation').click()